# How to make a score increment just +1 unity when Mario jump pipe?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a score increment of just +1 unity when Mario jumps the pipe, but the score increases by more than 1 unity when that happens. How can I do this?

```js
const mario = document.querySelector('.mario');
const pipe = document.querySelector('.pipe');

const jump = () => {
  mario.classList.add('jump');

  setTimeout(() => {
    mario.classList.remove('jump');
  }, 500);
}

let score = 0;

function scoreCount() {
  score++;

  document.querySelector('#score').innerHTML = `SCORE: ${score}`;
}

const loop = setInterval(() => {

  const pipePosition = pipe.offsetLeft;
  const marioPosition = +window.getComputedStyle(mario).bottom.replace('px', '');

  if (pipePosition < 0 && marioPosition >= 80) {
    scoreCount();
  }

  if (pipePosition <= 120 && pipePosition > 0 && marioPosition < 80) {

    pipe.style.animation = 'none';
    pipe.style.left = `${pipePosition}px`;

    mario.style.animation = 'none';
    mario.style.bottom = `${marioPosition}px`;

    mario.src = './marioImages/game-over.png';
    mario.style.width = '75px';
    mario.style.margin = '50px';

    clearInterval(loop);
  }
}, 10)

document.addEventListener('keydown', jump);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#score {
  font-family: 'Super Mario 256';
  margin: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.game-board {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(35, 160, 35);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(#87CEEB, #E0F6FF);
}

.pipe {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 80px;
  animation: pipe-animation 1.5s infinite linear;
}

.mario {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.jump {
  animation: jump 500ms ease-out;
}

.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  animation: clouds-animation 4s infinite linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes pipe-animation {
  from {
    right: -80px;
  }
  to {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes jump {
  0% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
  40% {
    bottom: 180px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 180px;
  }
  60% {
    bottom: 180px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes clouds-animation {
  from {
    right: -500px;
  }
  to {
    right: 100%;
  }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Super Mario 256';
  src: url(/marioFont/SuperMario256.ttf);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="marioCSS/mario.css">
  <script src="marioJS/mario.js" defer></script>
  <title>Mario Jump</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game-board">
    <h2 id="score">SCORE: 0</h2>
    <img src="marioImages/clouds.png" class="clouds">
    <img src="marioImages/mario.gif" class="mario">
    <img src="marioImages/pipe.png" class="pipe">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to create a function `scoreCount` to increment the score.

And then I called the `scoreCount` function into the 'loop' for when 'pipePosition' get out of the window, adding +1 to the score.

But it increments much more than 1.

Comment: You’re calling `scoreCount` inside a setInterval loop, which does increment it 1 every time, but it keeps repeating. Add a variable “scoreSet” in the script, then set it to `true` when the score increments, and make sure to block the score increment if `scoreSet` is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that `scoreCount()` is called inside a setInterval loop, which will keep calling the function and increment the score repeatedly.

If you still want it inside the loop, I recommend the following:

- Create a global variable “scoreSet” and set it to `false`
- Add an `if` statement to check if “scoreSet” is true
- If it is true, block the score from incrementing again
- If it is false, let it increment the score, but set `scoreSet` to true

Final code using this example:

```js
const mario = document.querySelector('.mario');
const pipe = document.querySelector('.pipe');

const jump = () => {
  mario.classList.add('jump');
  setTimeout(() => {
    mario.classList.remove('jump');
  }, 500);
}

let score = 0;
let scoreSet = false; // Variable to check whether you already incremented the score

function scoreCount() {
  if (!scoreSet) {
    score++;
    scoreSet = true;
  }

  document.querySelector('#score').innerHTML = `SCORE: ${score}`;
}
const loop = setInterval(() => {
  const pipePosition = pipe.offsetLeft;
  const marioPosition = +window.getComputedStyle(mario).bottom.replace('px', '');
  if (pipePosition < 0 && marioPosition >= 80) {
    scoreCount();
  }
  if (pipePosition <= 120 && pipePosition > 0 && marioPosition < 80) {
    pipe.style.animation = 'none';
    pipe.style.left = `${pipePosition}px`;
    mario.style.animation = 'none';
    mario.style.bottom = `${marioPosition}px`;
    mario.src = './marioImages/game-over.png';
    mario.style.width = '75px';
    mario.style.margin = '50px';
    clearInterval(loop);
  }
}, 10);

document.addEventListener('keydown', jump);
```

And if you want to increment the score again sometime in the script, just use “scoreSet = false”.